# Scatter with different colors

Tags: matlab

If I have

```
matrix=
    0.0494    2.3691
   -0.0973    0.8026
   -0.3040   -0.0861
   -0.0626    2.5688
   -0.4144    0.7054
    0.0633   -0.0991
   -0.8386   -1.2229
    1.8929    2.6260
    1.7687    2.3963
    1.8243   -0.5543
    1.9272   -0.3946
   -0.0682    1.7404
   -0.1180    2.2323
    0.4071   -0.1878
    0.6406    2.5602
   -0.2144    2.0014
    0.1091   -0.1874
   -0.1102    0.2922
```

How Would you plot one column in a color and other in a different color, or some of them in one color

```
scatter(matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2), 'b','+');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scatter` does not plot each column separately. It is `column 1` vs `column 2`. So, each point on the scatter plot is made up of both columns. In other words, there is no difference between `scatter(x,y)` and `plot(x,y,'o')`. However, `scatter` has other features, which is why it is available as a different function. If you were just trying to plot each column separately with two colors, you can simply do `plot(matrix,'o')` and MATLAB should automatically assign blue for the first column and green for the second.

`scatter` also takes a colormap as an argument. So if you intended to plot half your data (both columns) one color and the rest another, you can try this

```
nRows=size(matrix,1);
red=repmat([1,0,0],fix(nRows/2),1);%# use fix so that you don't get an error if nRows is not even.
green=repmat([0,1,0],nRows-fix(nRows/2),1);
scatter(matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2),[],[red;green]);
```

Comment: `[red;green]` didn't work for me. I had to use `['red';'green']`.

Comment: @DuckMaestro You didn't use the definitions of `red` and `green` I had defined here then...

Comment: I'm blind as a bat. -.-  Though in fairness I'm not used to minimal whitespace.

Comment: Yeah, my work code is well indented with adequate whitespace (I use vim, so even the `=` signs are aligned up). This was written during a phase when I was severely addicted to SO and was trying to crank out answers as fast as I could... all indenting/formatting went out the window in the quest to be the first to answer :)